# Correct unit testing

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, ldap, phpunit

I started using unit and functionality test with this project and because of this I have some questions:

Im working with the symfony php framework. And I have a doctrine like LDAP ORM service.

Furthermore I have a user repository (as a service) which depends on the LDAP ORM service, the logger and a validation service.

Now I want to write a unit test for the addUser function of the UserRepo.
It will internally call: getNewUidNumber, userToEntities, doesUserExist and getUserByUid.

My question is:
Should I mock all these internal function to just test the addUser function? Would that be against the unit test idea (just test the API).

Or should I just mock the LDAP ORM service, the Logger, and the validation  service, so that the class calls all internal functions? But this would cause a huge test function with a lot of mocking because I have to mock the repositories for all internal repositories calls.

Or should I start the symfony kernel and use the ServiceContainer to use the ORM LDAP service with a real test database. But wouldn't that be a functionally test and not a unit test?
I heard that its bad to have so many dependencies in a test. So I thought it would be bad to use the whole serviceContainer.

Adduser:

```
public function addUser(User $user)
{
    $pbnlAccount = $this->userToEntities($user);

    if(!$this->doesUserExist($user)) {
        $pbnlAccount->setUidNumber($this->getNewUidNumber());
        $this->ldapEntityManager->persist($pbnlAccount);
        $this->ldapEntityManager->flush();
    }
    else {
        throw new UserAlreadyExistException("The user ".$user->getUid()." already exists.");
    }

    return $this->getUserByUid($user->getUid());
}
```

For more code, like the internal functions:
https://gist.github.com/NKPmedia/4a6ee55b6bb96e8af409debd98950678

Thanks
Paul

Comment: How about sharing some code of the *system under test*?

Comment: Just wait a minute!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like to rewrite the method a tiny bit, if I may.

```
public function addUser(User $user)
{
    if ($this->doesUserExist($user)) {
        throw new UserAlreadyExistException("The user ".$user->getUid()." already exists.");
    }

    // ... shortened for brevity
    $pbnlAccount = $this->userToEntities($user);
    $this->ldapEntityManager->persist($pbnlAccount);
}
```

The other relevant method is:

```
private function doesUserExist(User $user)
{
    $users = $this->ldapRepository->findByUid($user->getUid());
    return count($users) === 1;
}
```

Immediately we can see that we basically have two tests:

- We test that the method throws when the user exists
- We test that the method persists a PbnlAccount if the user *does not* exist.

If you do not see why we have these two tests, note that there are 2 possible "flows" in this method: one where the block inside the if statement is executed, and one where it is not executed.

Lets tackle the first one:

```
public function testAddUserThrowsWhenUserExistsAlready()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUid('123');

    $ldapRepositoryMock = $this->createMock(LdapRepository::class);
    $ldapRepositoryMock
        ->method('findByUid')
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->with('123')
        ->willReturn(new PbnlAccount());

    $userRepository = new UserRepository($ldapRepositoryMock);

    $this->expectException(UserAlreadyExistException::class);
    $userRepository->addUser($user);    
}
```

The second test is left as an exercise for the reader :)

*Yes* you *will* have to do some mocking in your case. You wil need to mock the LdapRepository and LdapEntityManager both in this case.

Note 1: this code probably is not runnable, since I do not know the exact details of your code base (and I wrote this off the top of my head), but that is beside the point. The point is that you want to test for the exception.

Note 2: 
I would rename your function to `createNewPbnlAccountForUser(User $user)` which is longer, but more descriptive of what it actually does.

Note 3:
I am not sure why you are returning `$this->getUserByUid()` since that seems redundant (you already have the User right there), so I am ommitting that case.

Comment: Nice! I think I will do it like that. This will be a lot of mocking, but probably the best way.

Comment: @leet I recommend you get some books on the subject of testing/clean code as well, otherwise testing might very well be a very frustrating experience. (I recommend "Working with Legacy Code" and "Clean Code")

Comment: Wouldn't you mock `User` as well? So as to only check the behaviors of the class under test?

Comment: @ishegg Personally I would not. It takes too much effort to mock *everything* and creates very fragile tests, in my opinion. I only mock objects to 1. Return a certain value or 2. To verify method calls. In this case, were we to ever rename the getUid() method to something else, we would have to change *every* mock as well, since my IDE (PhpStorm) doesn't do that for me.

Comment: Oh I forgot one: 3. If the object is expesive to create or does database calls, they need to be mocked as well, obviously. We can be fairly certain that a User is not expensive to create nor that it does database queries (barring ActiveRecord). If it *is* expensive, by all means, mock the User class too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock ldapEntityManager and all repository services but not the internal function.And as you said, don't boot kernel in unit test. So, you should test all cases with success and throwing exception (make sure to check all behaviour)

Comment: Ok and is it better to hard code how often the tested function should call a mocked repo function. Or should I just use $this->any().

Comment: use always $this->at(index) instead of any() to manipulate better the tested case.

Comment: yes that means at 0 for example, you call methods with $param0 and return some $value0 and the same methods at 1 is called with $param1 and returned some different $value1 ect So for this example, if you make $this->any() thant means you consider the two different call for same methos are the same

Comment: I see! I have such a case. So then its better to user something like this:`$mock->expects($this->exactly(2))
     ->method('set')
     ->withConsecutive(
         [$this->equalTo('foo'), $this->greaterThan(0)],
         [$this->equalTo('bar'), $this->greaterThan(0)]
       );` But

Comment: But when I want to make a function that build a reusable mock that fits on more than one test. Would it be ok to use any.

Comment: if methods not changed in any cases, you can use any and make reusable private mock function to use for more one tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform a unit test, you should mock all collaborators.
Now, entity managers, ldap services and so on should not be mocked ([read more here](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own)).

Moreover, if you happen to be in a situation where the Arrange part (set mocks, stubs, and  so on) is painful and take "a lot" of the test, maybe this is a smell that your class has too many responsibility (is doing too much things).

That said, when I do unit test, I would like the test to fail only for an **internal** (to the class) reason, not because I've changed a collaborator line that messes up all my tests.